# Stage control for "go to x,y"

Tags: simulation, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,
I was wondering if there is a package that I could use to send a simulated stage robot from point A to point B. I see that one can publish to cmd_vel for a particular robot. However I want to avoid doing the path planning myself. My first idea was to use move_base, however I intend to use several simulated robots, so I am not sure if I can launch several move_base instances. Plus it would be overkill. I hear Stage_Controller has some capabilities, though I couldnt find any documentation regarding "go to goal" capabilities.
Thank you,
Ammar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47849/stage-control-for-%22go-to-x,y%22/) by [Ammar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2639/ammar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 289 on 2012-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest to use move_base. It should definitely be possible to run multiple instances in parallel.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0